# UWP - Pictures library - Access is denied

Tags: c#, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have following code:

```
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Document";
savePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = photo;
await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

and my appxmanifest looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="" Publisher="" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName></DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName></PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="zalegaNaMagazynie.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

But I always get an 'Access is denied' error when I'm debugging.
I'm using this C# code after taking a photo because I need to convert it to Base64 and I get some tutorials where to do that I must save image first, then use streams etc. or maybe you have a better solution to converting image to Base64. I need Base64 to send a picture to web API through POST method using HttpClient.

Comment: Hi @Pawel, welcome to StackOverflow! To help the S.O. users, the clarity of your question is important. I believe you are asking for several things apart from the `Access Denied` error. Please edit your question and break them down. It would also help if you could specify what solutions you have tried so far. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can save file in local folder. You don't need any capabilities in manifest for it.

```
StorageFile sf =  await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename.txt");
```

By the way HttpClient could be used if you want to send small file. It's not recommended for large data